# Why does sychrotron radiation only involve relativistic electrons?

Tags: radiation

I'm reading [this](https://www.cv.nrao.edu/%7Esransom/web/Ch4.html) chapter of *Essential Radio Astronomy*.

It says that we can divide bremsstrahlung into electric or magnetic breaking radiation, depending on which field is the source of the acceleration of electrons. **Synchrotron radiation** is another name for magnetic breaking radiation, and it is usually non-thermal, because the relativistic electrons creating the emissions tend to have a power-law distribution.

**My question** would be: why does synchrotron radiation only occur in the case of relativistic electrons? Why cannot any non-relativistic electron that is moving in the presence of a magnetic field emit synchtron radiation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They can, but it would be called cyclotron emission. The difference is that cyclotron emission occurs at a discrete frequency for a given B-field, whereas the relativistic electrons emit at a broad spread of frequencies that form a continuum under realistic conditions.

Hence this is a terminology thing as well as a physics thing. Cyclotron radiation becomes synchrotron radiation as the electrons become relativistic.

Comment: And cyclotron radiation is beamed with a certain opening angle, which is a purely relativistic effect.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Synchrotron radiation can be beamed (if the B-field is spatially uniform). Cyclotron radiation is not.

Comment: This is really interesting decades ago I worked at a cyclotron lab, these days at a synchrotron lab. I never thought about cyclotron radiation at the former and make great use of the forward-emitted synchrotron radiation (and the narrow and coherent beams from [wigglers and undulators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/480966/83380) and now I can't stop wondering what happens between the two limits. It seems that the mechanisms are pretty different, so both happen to some extent even in both limits, it's just a question of amplitudes. Now I'll go off and think about it...

Comment: Thank you @ProfRob for the answer!

Comment: @uhoh that is quite an interesting question!

Comment: @uhoh It's called gyro-synchrotron radiation.